# Swype keyboard overlaps on EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have 2 Linear layouts. One containing a list view and another with an EditText.
When I am typing in EditText swype keyboard overlaps on it.
How can i make EditText floating? (means when swype keyboard comes EditText should stand a top of it. I have seen such a facility on most Apps.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"

in your manifest file where your activity is declared

Comment: Does not work, most of the people suggest ScrollView as container.